# Как изменить цвет для окна консоли c++

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Как можно изменить цвет консоли своего приложения на C++? Нужно использовать *Windows.h*?

Comment: если вы задумаетесь о кросплатформенности, то могу порекомендовать `curses`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам и отвечу.

**Внимание! Представленные ниже способы подходят только для Windows систем!** Для Linux используйте библиотеку `ncurses`.

---

Можно менять цвет фона окна и символов без дополнительных библиотек, простой функцией `system()`. Достаточно написать, например, `system("color F0")` и будет установлен белый фон (F) и чёрный текст (0). Можно писать и наоборот, например: `system("color 3F");` установит голубой фон и белый текст.

---

Список цветов:

- 0 — черный
- 1 — синий
- 2 — зеленый
- 3 — голубой
- 4 — красный
- 5 — лиловый
- 6 — желтый
- 7 — белый
- 8 — серый
- 9 — свело-синий
- A — светло-зеленый
- B — светло-голубой
- С — светло-красный
- E — светло-желтый
- F — ярко-белый

Можно использовать функцию `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` из *Windows.h*:

```
HANDLE h;
h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //получаем наше окно, в котором нужно изменить цвет
```

И установим жёлтый цвет на зелёном фоне:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, (((2 << 4) | 14)));
```

Что же это за страшная функция? Если кратко: число смещается на 4 бита влево и объединяется со вторым в результате логического ИЛИ. Эти действия объединят числа, чтобы функция установила нужный цвет и фон. Если интересно, можно взять результат этих операций (в данном случае 46) и скормить их функции:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 46);
```

И вы получите такой же результат. Но настраивать гораздо удобнее по двум числа (первая отвечает за фон, вторая за текст).

---

Вот список цветов для этой функции:

- Чёрный - 0
- Синий - 1
- Зелёный - 2
- Голубой - 3
- Красный - 4
- Пурпурный - 5
- Коричневый - 6
- Светло-серый - 7
- Тёмно-серый - 8
- Светло-синий - 9
- Светло-зелёный - 10
- Светло-голубой - 11
- Светло-красный- 12
- Светло-пурпурный - 13
- Жёлтый - 14
- Белый - 15

**Внимание!** Функция `system("color ...")` устанавливает цвет для всей консоли и всех символов, а `SetConsoleTextAttribute();` только для символов и той части консоли, которая находится под ними. [image: примеры функций]

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить, что это работает только под Windows.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, добавлю